# Android Cross Compilation JNI -> No implementation found for

Tags: android, c, android-studio, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am using a shared library libToon-c.so in my android app.

When running this app via the Android Virtual Device (AVD), the shared library is loaded and running without any problems.

**However when attempting to load the library on to a phone (Google Pixel) the following error is shown**

```
E/linker: "/data/app/com.example.androidsharedlibscratch-a6Mv8edOnQ2q6HbbixecrQ==/lib/arm64/libToon-c.so": ignoring DT_PREINIT_ARRAY in shared library! E/haredlibscratc: No implementation found for long com.example.androidsharedlibscratch.Toon.createToon() (tried Java_com_example_androidsharedlibscratch_Toon_createToon and Java_com_example_androidsharedlibscratch_Toon_createToon__) D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.androidsharedlibscratch, PID: 18368
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.example.androidsharedlibscratch.Toon.createToon() (tried Java_com_example_androidsharedlibscratch_Toon_createToon and Java_com_example_androidsharedlibscratch_Toon_createToon__)
        at com.example.androidsharedlibscratch.Toon.createToon(Native Method)
        at com.example.androidsharedlibscratch.Toon.<init>(Toon.java:44)
        at com.example.androidsharedlibscratch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**The toonJni.h contains the following function definition**

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_androidsharedlibscratch_Toon_createToon
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

**The corresponding toonJni.cpp file contains the following function implementation:**

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_androidsharedlibscratch_Toon_createToon(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    ...
    return (reinterpret_cast<jlong>(toon));
}
```

**This shared library has been compiled for Android using the following standalone toolchains:**

- arm64 platform using the aarch64-linux-android toolchain
- x86 platform using the i686-linux-anrdoid toolchain

**In order to include the library in the project the .so file has been put in the jniLibs folder as per below:**

- src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a (contains arm64 library)
- src/main/jniLibs/x86 (contains x86 library)

**The following code has been added to in the build.gradle to include the jni files:**

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs 'src/main/jniLibs'
        }
    }
```

**The toonJni.h contains the extern c { ... } directive**

**The toonJni.h file is generated by using the following javac command**

```
javac -h . Toon.java
```

**The apk has been built, extracted and verified  to contain the libToon-c.so file**

**The following commands have also been used verify that the libToon-c.so is in the app folder on the device (Google Pixel)**

```
adb shell dumpsys package packages | grep androidsharedlibscratch
adb ls /data/app/com.example.androidsharedlibscratch-foqHDywOpE_dDPgTCtTttw==/lib/arm64
```

**Below is the command and the results from the check for name mangling:**

```
android-ndk-r21/build/toolchain/bin/aarch64-linux-android-nm android_studio_scratch/AndroidSharedLibScratch/app/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libToon-c.so

000000000000d570 T Java_com_example_androidsharedlibscratch_Toon_createToon
```

**Added the following JNI_OnLoad in the .cpp and .h files (below) as @Botje specified. The toonLib loaded successfully is not showing up in the android studio logcat (log level is set to verbose).**

Definition in toonJni.h:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved);
```

Implementation in toonJni.cpp:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    JNIEnv* env;
    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "toonlib", "toonlib loaded successfully");

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Comment: Does your `jni.cpp` also include the header generated by `javac -h`? Check the contents of the `.so` file with `arm-linux-androideabi-nm` or `aarch64-linux-android-nm` to make sure the name was not mangled.

Comment: yes, I have the following includes in my toonJni.cpp file, include toonJni.h, include <iostream>, include <syslog.h>

Comment: @Botje, ive added the results from checking the .so file.

Comment: @Botje, I did the name mangling check on my development machine, is it possible (or worth it) to do this check on the android device?

Comment: No, that does not matter. Can you put an Android log statement in your `JNI_Onload` function to prove that the library is loaded?

Comment: @Botje, ive added the JNI_OnLoad as specified in the edit, but the app is crashing now. Is the JNI_OnLoad implemented correctly?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use `syslog`, but the [android logging functions](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging) instead.

Comment: @botje, ive added the results of the __android_log_print

Comment: You're going to have to use a native debugger to see where and why it crashes. Perhaps that "ignoring DT_PREINIT_ARRAY in shared library!" warning skips some initialization, or it could be a red herring.

Comment: Im not familiar with native debuggers, could you point me in the direction of one?

Comment: The Android documentation is quite comprehensive: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/debug

Comment: Ive currently packaged the jni.h and jni.cpp files into the .so library. Is this supposed to be the case? Or should the jni.h and jni.cpp files be provided in a different way?

Comment: Based on this link: https://ctf-wiki.github.io/ctf-wiki/android/basic_operating_mechanism/native_layer/so/ it does not look like the DT_PREINIT_ARRAY is the issue.